# WebGL texture with transparency mipmappable? Turns opaque when mipmapping turned on

Tags: webgl, transparency, mipmaps

The simple question is - is there any difference between `gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST` and `gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`? I've used the first, with bad results (see below) and found the second on the web. Interestingly, both are defined (in Chrome), and I wonder what their difference is.

The real question is - If I have a texture atlas with transparency (containing glyphs), can I use mipmapping? When zooming to small sizes, the glyphs flicker, which I want to eliminate by mipmapping.

But when I turn on mipmapping (only changing the `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` from `LINEAR` to `LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, and calling `generateMipmap()` afterwards), the transparency is completely gone and the entire texture turns black.

I understand that mipmapping may cause bleeding of the black ink into the transparent area, but not fill the entire texture at all mipmap levels (including the original size).

What scrap of knowledge do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml)

GL_NEAREST

> Returns the value of the texture element that is nearest (in Manhattan distance) to the center of the pixel being textured.

GL_LINEAR

> Returns the weighted average of the four texture elements that are closest to the center of the pixel being textured.

GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST

> Chooses the mipmap that most closely matches the size of the pixel being textured and uses the GL_NEAREST criterion (the texture element nearest to the center of the pixel) to produce a texture value.

GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST

> Chooses the mipmap that most closely matches the size of the pixel being textured and uses the GL_LINEAR criterion (a weighted average of the four texture elements that are closest to the center of the pixel) to produce a texture value.

GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR

> Chooses the two mipmaps that most closely match the size of the pixel being textured and uses the GL_NEAREST criterion (the texture element nearest to the center of the pixel) to produce a texture value from each mipmap. The final texture value is a weighted average of those two values.

GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR

> Chooses the two mipmaps that most closely match the size of the pixel being textured and uses the GL_LINEAR criterion (a weighted average of the four texture elements that are closest to the center of the pixel) to produce a texture value from each mipmap. The final texture value is a weighted average of those two values.

As for why your stuff turns black have you checked the JavaScript console for errors? The most likely reason is your texture is not a power of 2 in both dimensions. If that's the case, trying to use mips by switching from `gl.LINEAR` to `gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST` will not work because in WebGL mips are not supported textures that are not a power of 2 in both dimensions.

Comment: Gregg, once again, you made my day! May the Power Of Two be with you - thanks!